# Google Sheets equivalent to Excel Start: End Formula?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm very familiar with MS Excel, but not so much with GSheets.
I'm working on an app that explicitly uses Google Spreadsheets.

Is something like this `=SUM(SHEET1:SHEET5!A1)` possible in GSheets?

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14112/in-google-spreadshets-how-can-you-loop-through-all-available-sheets-not-knowing

Comment: Yes, you're totally right!
I asked just in case :)
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To:

> SUM using 3D ranges in Sheets by ElephantManGuy 26/01/2016

From [James/mreighties](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/DMsuY3wMxUI) a "Platinum Top Contributor":

```
That feature is still not available in Google Sheets
```

Answer was the same day but still applies.
Can however be achieved with GAS (and there is code linked to the referenced thread).